# nodejs config module optimist or nconf?

Tags: node.js

I've just started writing my first app with NodeJS and I must say it's a pleasure learning how to work with :)

I've reached the point where I'm making some configuration before starting the server, and I would like to load the config from a `config.json` file.

I have found a few ways so far, either request that json file and leaver node require parse it, use a `config.js` file and export my config, use [nconf](https://github.com/flatiron/nconf), which seems pretty easy to use, or the last option I've seen is using [optimist](https://github.com/substack/node-optimist) which I thought it would be better than ncond. Though I'm starting to think that the latter, optimist, can only be used for parsing arguments from the node cli.

So I'm asking here, can I use node optimist to get my config from a file, or, if not, should I use nconf ? Or maybe, there's something even better and lightweight out there that I don't know of ? (my options at this point are pretty vague, since I'm not sure if at some point I would like to parse any config from the cli).

Comment: If you want, you can just do `require("./config.json")`. Node.js has built-in support for JSON files. Something like nconf is only relevant if you want to merge different config objects.

Comment: What about the async module, doesn't that one have a method for merging objects ? So unless I need any arguments from cli, nconf would be an overhead, right ?

Comment: Async doesn't merge objects. Async is for dealing with asynchronous functions, in particular using them in a batch-wise fashion. [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) does have a "defaults" function, which can be used to add default values to an object, but only on one-level. Searching npm for "deep extend" gives various packages though.

Comment: I understand, I seem to have a hard time making the difference between all the modules out there :) I have been using underscore for a while now on the frontend, in favor of jQuery when developing for mobile, I usually used the `_.extend()` function for that, and when I needed to do a recursive merge I used jQuery's recursive version ( the extend method they have has an option for doing recursive object merging ). But to get back to the subject of the question, just reading the JSON file it's a more convenient way rather than using a lib for that ?

Comment: Well I mentioned the possibility because just for the use case *you* describe it's not necessary to bring in a module. It's good to know what node itself can do. And also handy if you can serve yourself with more general-purpose libraries. Big chance you use underscore somewhere else. Plus you can tailor your way of configuring to your unique needs. I recommend to first do it yourself, then if you feel you're reinventing the wheel (and not having fun while doing so), look for a module. But requiring (and nesting modules) is the bread and butter of Node.

Comment: Sounds fair to me @MerynStol :) Off topic, what about Recess module, I've been trying for an hour or so to configure it programmatic to compile a less file ( which is importing other less ) and lint it. I cannot figure it out how, I keep getting some odd erros in the node console :) And how would I go about having a destination file where all that compile css would go ?

Comment: I think you'd be better off asking a separate question about that. I don't have experience with less. I happen to prefer Stylus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use a config.js file like this:

```
var config = {}
config.web = {};
config.debug = {};

config.server_name =  'MyServerName';
config.web.port = process.env.WEB_PORT || 32768;

config.debug.verbositylevel = 3;

module.exports = config;
```

then i can just call config variables like this:

```
var port = config.web.port;
```

I find it much easier to maintain like this. Hope that helps you.

Comment: This seems the simplest solution I've seen so far, though I would like to keep my config in a json file, or what are your inputs on that ?

Comment: I would then say use nconf if you want to do that :)

Comment: What about using the `exports.config= function(request, response) { return config; };`, this will require me to do a `new config()` when I do the `.request()` in the other file, right ?

Answer (score 5):

I use [dotenv](https://github.com/scottmotte/dotenv). It's as easy as:

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
```

Then you just create a .env file with your configuration settings.

```
S3_BUCKET=YOURS3BUCKET
SECRET_KEY=YOURSECRETKEYGOESHERE
```

Disclaimer: I'm the creator, and didn't find the config.json file approach useful in production environments. I prefer getting configuration from my environment variables.

Comment: I use the same but in ruby :)

Comment: Nice. And that's where the inspiration came from. I use the same in ruby too.

Answer (score 2):

6 years later and the answer should have been: Use Nconf. it's awesome.

```js
//
// yourrepo/src/options.js
//
const nconf = require('nconf');

// the order is important
// from top to bottom, a value is 
// only stored if it isn't found 
// in the preceding store.

// env values win all the time
// but only if the are prefixed with our appname ;)

nconf.env({
  separator: '__',
  match: /^YOURAPPNAME__/,
  lowerCase: true,
  parseValues: true,
  transform(obj) {
    obj.key.replace(/^YOURAPPNAME__/, '');
    return obj;
  },
});


// if it's not in env but it's here in argv, then it wins
// note this is just passed through to [yargs](https://github.com/yargs/yargs)
nconf.argv({
  port: {
    type: 'number'
  },
})

// if you have a file somewhere up the tree called .yourappnamerc
// and it has the json key of port... then it wins over the default below.
nconf.file({
  file: '.yourappnamerc'
  search: true
})


// still not found, then we use the default.
nconf.defaults({
  port: 3000
})


module.exports = nconf.get();
```

then in any other file

```
const options = require('./options');

console.log(`PORT: ${options.port}`);
```

now you can run your project like :

```
$ yarn start
# prints PORT: 3000

$ YOURAPPNAME__PORT=1337 yarn start
# prints PORT: 1337

$ yarn start --port=8000
# prints PORT: 8000

$ echo '{ "port": 10000 }' > .yourappnamerc
$ yarn start
# prints PORT: 10000
```

and if you forget what options you have

```sh
$ yarn start --help
# prints out all the options
```